# Recycler view con arraylist de checkboxes. No se muestra el texto de los checkboxes

Tags: android, android-studio

quiero mostrar por pantalla una lista de checkboxes que estan contenidas en un arraylist. Para ello utilizo un recyclerview. El problema que tengo es que se me muestran los checkboxes pero no su texto.
Este es el codigo del activity main donde creo el recycler view en un linearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1500px"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:text="Aceptar" />
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

este el item_list, que es donde defino los datos que se van a mostrar en el recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/idDato"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

este el adapter, donde defino todo lo necesario para hacer la conexion entre los datos y el recyclerview:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.CharSequence;

public class adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter.ViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<CheckBox> listDatos;

    public adapter(ArrayList<CheckBox> listDatos) {
        this.listDatos = listDatos;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemlist,null,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.asignarDatos(listDatos.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listDatos.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CheckBox dato;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            dato=itemView.findViewById(R.id.idDato);
        }

        public void asignarDatos(CheckBox s) {
            dato=s;

        }
    }
}
```

y este el mainActivity, donde asigno el texto del checkbox: `movil.setText("Movil");`

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import java.lang.CharSequence;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList <CheckBox> listDatos;
    RecyclerView recycler;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recycler=findViewById(R.id.recyclerId);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        listDatos=new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
        CheckBox television=new CheckBox(this);
        television.setText("Television");
        CheckBox movil=new CheckBox(this);
        movil.setText("Movil");
        listDatos.add(television);
        listDatos.add(movil);
        adapter a = new adapter(listDatos);
        recycler.setAdapter(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu aproximaciòn es un poco incorrecta, donde debes asignar los textos debe ser dentro de `onBindViewHolder()`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
  ...
  ... 
  ...    
  holder.dato.setText("Television");
}
```

Si deseas que se muestren los textos podrìas enviar al adapter una lista de textos

```
public adapter(ArrayList<String> listDatos) {
        this.listDatos = listDatos;
    }
```

ya que el `CheckBox` ya se encuentra en el layout y no es necesario enviar una lista de Checkboxs.

Comment: pero yo quiero que se me muestre el checkbox con su texto al lado (indicando la opcion que se elige). Si mando un arraylist de strings se me va a mostrar solo el texto y no el checkbox.

Comment: El widget Checkbox tiene una propiedad para asignar texto, te sugiero revises primeramente como funciona el Checkbox y como asignarle el texto ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194711/checkbox-settext-do-not-work-android

Comment: ya asigno el texto asi en al mainactivity:  `CheckBox movil=new CheckBox(this);
        movil.setText("Movil");`

Comment: lo he solucionado con esto: `public void asignarDatos(CheckBox s) {
            dato.setText(s.getText());`
        }